# React, Redux with immutable.js : Cannot get correct state data when delete one items from a list

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am practicing a Todo list with React 16, Redux and immutable.js, however when deleting one item from a list of items in UI (please see the attachment). It will delete all the items and only left one which cannot be deleted. When adding item, it works fine, but no idea why the data in the state behaves incorrectly. Does anyone knows what's wrong with my code? Thank you so much in advanced:

```
import { fromJS } from  'immutable';
import * as constants from './actionTypes';

const todoState = fromJS({
        isCompleted : false,
        inputValue : '',
        list: []
})

const todoReducer = function(state = todoState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case constants.ADD_ITEM: 
            const list = state.get('list');
            const inputValue = action.payload;
            return state.set('list', [...list, {inputValue, isCompleted : false}]);
        case constants.REMOVE_ITEM:  {
            const list = state.get('list');
            const index = action.payload; // works correctly
            const newList = list.splice(index, 1);
            // will delete all the items and only left one which cannot be deleted
            return state.set('list', newList);
        }
        case constants.CHECK_ITEM:
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default todoReducer;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value returned from [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is a new array containing the **deleted** items, not the remaining items. The original array is mutated.

You could achieve the desired result by copying the array, splicing the copy, then returning it.

```
const newList = [...list];
newList.splice(index, 1);
return state.set('list', newList);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I made a change:  function getNewList (list, index) {
    return list.filter(item => list.indexOf(item) !== index);
}  const newList = getNewList(list, index);   it works! BTW, do you think using filter() is a good practice to solve this issue?

Comment: Thank you! After your hint, I used filter(), but I think your way is better

Comment: @ZichenMa I think `filter` is fine. You could avoid the call to `indexOf` by using the second argument passed to the filter callback: `list.filter((item, itemIndex) => itemIndex !== index)`